# Filling result with prefix 0 to a fixed width

Tags: sql, prefix

I have the following challenge. The goal is to create fixed-width fields of 6 characters. If the table field only contains three characters, then there should be three characters prefixed with 0. Example

the source is a table with account limits

Limit

> 201
>
> 4000

result

> Limit
>
> 000201
>
> 004000

I have the following code, but this will postfix the value, and I need to prefix the limit values with 0's.

SELECT
REPLACE(CAST(LIMIT AS NCHAR(6)), SPACE(1),'0') AS Accountlimit
FROM DWH.limit

Comment: The name of the database would be handy

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2012 an on you can use the `FORMAT` function like this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(201, '000000')
```

The result of above statement will be the string "000201"

Answer (score 0):

How about doing the following

1. Prefix the string with six zeros (so you will have enough of them)
2. Fetch the last six letters of that string (trim off those that you do not require)

i.e.

```
select substr(concat('000000', limit)), -6, 6) ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The environment is sql server 2008. Are there any options for this environment?